A problem related to finite Galois theory.
Suppose $K/k$ be a finite Galois extension with the Galois group $G=\{\sigma_1=\text{id} , .. , \sigma_n$} And consider the diagonal matrices that of the form $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda, \sigma_2(\lambda),.. , \sigma_n(\lambda))$ for $\lambda\in K$. I want to show that the K subalgebra generated by these type of matrices is the entire diagonal subalgebra of $M_n(K)$.
I was trying to use the Normal Basis Theorem but I'm unable to proceed.

Use the fact that $K \otimes_k K \cong K^n$ under the map $\alpha \otimes_k \beta \mapsto (\alpha\sigma_1(\beta), \ldots, \alpha \sigma_n(\beta))$. Your question is now asking whether $K \otimes_k K$ is spanned by the elements $1 \otimes_k \beta$ as a left $K$-module, which is clearly true.
